# Is the series converges or diverges? $\frac{n}{n+1}^{(n^{\frac{3}{2}})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

$\sum_{n\geq 1}^{}\frac{n}{n+1}^{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

I need some help please, I have no idea where to approach the solution

Comment: Marginally less than $2.0764856558$, and the first $100$ terms will get you over $2.075$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By observing that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\ln \left(1+\frac1n \right) \sim \frac1n
$$ one may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left ( \frac{n}{n+1} \right )^{\large n^{3/2}}=e^{-\large n^{3/2}\ln \left(1+\frac1n \right)} \sim e^{-\sqrt{n}}
$$ which is a general term of a *convergent* series, as one may sees by using
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}n^2 \cdot e^{-\sqrt{n}}=0.
$$